# How to use PHP to connect to an Informix database remotely?

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, informix

We have an informix database(Version 7) running on unix (5). We need to connect to informix database from another server (Centos 6.9) using PHP(5.6) and need to update the informix data.

Is it required to install informix driver on centos server to access informix which is on another server? Because its giving Fatal error: `Uncaught exception 'PDOException'` with message `could not find driver` when trying to connect using the following code:

```
$dbh = new PDO("informix:host=$hostname;service=1516;database=$database;server=$informixserver; protocol=$protocolname;", $login, $password);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Informix driver. See here for details how:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-informix.php

Comment: Unable to find the Informix Client SDK from IBM.  Pls help with centos and csdk informix installation requirements

Comment: Here is the Informix SDK http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/csdk

Comment: I have successfully installed the pdo_informix driver . When i connect to remote server informix database using the following code:$dbh = new PDO("informix:host=$hostname;service=1516;database=$database;server=$informixserver; protocol=$protocolname;", $login, $password);, its giving Fatal error: SQLSTATE=HY000, SQLDriverConnect: -23101 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Unspecified System Error = -23101